# How to iterate on slices, 4 items at a time

Tags: go

How do I iterate through a Go slice 4 items at a time.

lets say I have `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`

I want a for loop to be able to get

```
[1,2,3,4] //First Iteration
[5,6,7,8] //Second Iteration
[9,10,11,12] //Third Iteration
[13,14,15,] // Fourth Iteration
```

I can do this in java and python but for golang I really dont have an idea.

Comment: This problem is straightforward as stated (see [PatrickMahomes2's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59494504/1256452)). Are you looking for something more generic, such as the ability to define an iterator with some argument `n` for how many elements to put into each sub-slice? If so, see, e.g., https://play.golang.org/p/O09ZsVNWV2D (I wrapped his code in a little function that takes a function to call).

Comment: @torek: In Go, we would likely write your code as https://play.golang.org/p/uUxR8Ct5O_W. See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: @peterSO: yes, I would have done that myself were I not starting with someone else's code fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    slice := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
    for i := 0; i < len(slice); i += 4 {
        var section []int
        if i > len(slice)-4 {
            section = slice[i:]
        } else {
            section = slice[i : i+4]
        }
        fmt.Println(section)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/kf7_OJcP13t

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
[9 10 11 12]
[13 14 15]
```

Comment: @torek I guess someone downvoted it because the author didn't try to explain his answer - just posted the code.

Answer (score 3):

> How To Iterate on Slices in Go, Iterating 4 items at a time. I want a
>   for loop.

---

In Go, readability is paramount. First we read the normal path, then we read the exception/error paths.

We write the normal path.

```
n := 4
for i := 0; i < len(s); i += n {
    ss := s[i : i+n]
    fmt.Println(ss)
}
```

We use `n` for the stride value throughout.

We write a little tweak that doesn't disturb the normal path to handle an exception, the end of the slice.

```
if n > len(s)-i {
    n = len(s) - i
}
```

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}
    n := 4
    for i := 0; i < len(s); i += n {
        if n > len(s)-i {
            n = len(s) - i
        }
        ss := s[i : i+n]
        fmt.Println(ss)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Vtpig2EeXB7

Output:

```
[1 2 3 4]
[5 6 7 8]
[9 10 11 12]
[13 14 15]
```